# Method returns "Optional[0]" instant of an int

Tags: java, interpolation, option-type

Hello quite a simple Question: I am supposed to write a method split(int[] array, int toSearch, int lower, int upper) that uses the interpolate method to find out where to split the array. It should return the index x where to split. My code looks like this:

```
private static int split(int[] array, int toSearch, int lower, int upper){
    int x = 0;
    int v = toSearch;
    int l = lower;
    int r = upper;
    x = l + (v-array[l])/(array[r]-array[l])*(r-l);
    return x;
}
private static int search(int[] array, int toSearch){
    int Stelle = 0;
    if(array.length > 0){
        int v = toSearch;
        int l = 0;
        int r = array.length - 1;
        int i = 0;
        Stelle = split(array, v, l, r);
        while(array[Stelle] != v){
            Stelle = split(array, v, l, r);
            l = Stelle + 1;
            i++;
            if(i>1000){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(array.length == 0){
        Stelle = -1;
    }
return Stelle;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int v = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int[] array = new int[args.length -1];
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]);
    }
    System.out.println(search(array, v));
}
```

The formula is right and the rest of the code where I use the method split works too (which is pretty weird) but the test for the method split itself doesn't work. I get the error : "Expecting <Optional[0]> to contain <1> but did not"
So what is Optional[0]? And why the hell does the rest of the code work if the split method doesn't function correctly? Thanks in advance!

Some people have asked about the Test Code so here it is:

```
 void testSplit() {
private static final int[] SEARCH_ARRAY = new int[]{2, 4, 7, 9, 12, 21, 26, 31, 37};
            var result1 = Program.execute(() -> SPLIT_METHOD.invoke(null, SEARCH_ARRAY, 7, 0, 8));
            var result2 = Program.execute(() -> SPLIT_METHOD.invoke(null, SEARCH_ARRAY, 21, 4, 8));
            var result3 = Program.execute(() -> SPLIT_METHOD.invoke(null, SEARCH_ARRAY, 21, 0, 8));
    
            assertThat(result1.getReturnValue()).contains(1);
            assertThat(result2.getReturnValue()).contains(5);
            assertThat(result3.getReturnValue()).contains(4);
        }
```

Comment: You didn't show us the code for the test.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can't see from your question what your test code looks like? In order to allow us to help, please include the full code required to reproduce the error.

Comment: I now included the Test Code

Comment: What type is `Program`?  What type is `SPLIT_METHOD`?  I still don't think you've shown us  enough code to figure this out.

Comment: You still have not provided the code that returns Optionals i.e. the `Program.execute` method. But the point of your test seems to be asserting that `split(SEARCH_ARRAY, 7, 0, 8)` returns 1, and the test fails because it returns 0. It looks like you're trying to write a binary search, is that right?

Comment: I'm guessing `Program` is something from a framework within which you write your code, a framework provided by your teachers. We have no idea what it is, and understanding how that works is crucial to answering your question. As is, your question remains unanswerable without more detail.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my problem was the way I defined x. For large enough values I would have x = 0 because x is int because the result of (v-array[l])/(array[r]-array[l]) was very often less than 1 which my method interpreted as 0. So all I had to do was write the (r-l) in front of the division and it worked out. I think the reason my program worked anyways was because just pure luck lol :D